# Using regular expressions to parse a line in Perl

Tags: regex, git, perl

So I'm making a program that stats git repositories but I'm having trouble getting a certain regular expression to work. Basically, I have a string that looks like this:

```
my $string = "5    2    gitc"
```

and a regular expression that looks like this:

```
my ($added, $removed) = $string =~ /([0-9]*) *([0-9]*) *[a-z]*/;
```

My goal is to store the first number as $added and the second number as $removed, but for some reason no value is being stored in $removed. So if I use the print statement:

```
print "-$added $removed-\n";
```

the output looks like:

```
-5 -
```

when I test that regular expression on regex 101 my capture groups appear to work fine so I'm kind of stumped as to why it doesn't work. Can anyone see a problem with my regular expression?

Comment: Is there possibly a tab character there?  When I run those two lines locally (ensuring space characters in $string) it works.  i.e. I get "-5 2-"

Comment: Are the numbers optional or should they definitely be there? If they should always be there, then try using `+` instead of `*`, like this: `/([0-9]+) +([0-9]+) +[a-z]+/`. There are fewer possible ways to match with `+`.

Comment: @Marty, That's a really good idea to check. Amending my suggestion: `/([0-9]+)[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]+[a-z]+/`

Comment: If there was a tab character how could I account for that? And yes the numbers are always there, but using + doesn't seem to give me the right results either.

Comment: Yes, It was a tab character all along. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: @Kyle - funny you should say that - I thought your advice was more relevant.  Perhaps combine both - note that \s is equivalent to [\ \t\r\n\f] which would cover tabs.  Using /x is always a big help.  Therefore we have /(\d+) \s+ (\d+) [a-z]+/x

Comment: @Marty: you probably need an extra `\s+` in there, as in: `/(\d+) \s+ (\d+) \s+ \w+/x` (using `\w` for 'word characters — upper and lower case, etc).

Answer (score 5):

As Kyle pointed out in the comments - if the digits *have* to be there then use `+` instead of `*` to reduce the number of possible matches the RE engine has to search through.  Also, since `\s` matches "whitespace" (defined [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) as `[\ \t\r\n\f]`), you can cover the possibillity of tab characters throwing the match off by using it instead of a literal space character.

Using `\s` to match whitespace also frees up the literal space character to assist with formatting in the regex itself.  To do that, use 'extended mode' regexs by adding a `/x` on the end of the specification.

Finally, as a general rule, test for a successful match before assigning to variables like so;

```
my $string = "5    2    gitc";
if ($string =~ /(\d+) \s+ (\d+) [a-z]+/x)  {
    my ($added, $removed) = ($1, $2);
}
else
    print "Failed match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
my ($added, $removed) = split ' ', $string;
```